# Sliding window aggregate Big Query 15 minute aggregation

Tags: time-series, google-bigquery, aggregate

I have a table like this

Row time    viewCount
1   00:00:00    31
2   00:00:01    44
3   00:00:02    78
4   00:00:03    71
5   00:00:04    72
6   00:00:05    73
7   00:00:06    64
8   00:00:07    70

I would like to aggregate this into

Row time    viewCount
1   00:00:00    31
2   00:15:00    445
3   00:30:00    700
4   00:45:00    500
5   01:00:04    121
6   01:15:00    475 
.
.
.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Note: you provided simplified example of your data and below follows it - so instead of each 15 minutes aggregation, it uses each 2 sec aggregation. This is for you to be able to easy test / play with it. It is easily can be adjusted to 15 minutes by changing `SECOND` to `MINUTE` in 3 places and `2` to `15` in 3 places. Also this example uses `TIME` data type for time field as it is in your example so it is limited to just 24 hour period  - most likely in your real data you have `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`. In this case you will also need to replace all `TIME_*` functions with respective `DATETIME_*` or `TIMESTAMP_*` functions

So, finally - the query is:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIME '00:00:00' time, 31 viewCount UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '00:00:01', 44 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '00:00:02', 78 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '00:00:03', 71 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '00:00:04', 72 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '00:00:05', 73 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '00:00:06', 64 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '00:00:07', 70 
),
period AS (
  SELECT MIN(time) min_time, MAX(time) max_time, TIME_DIFF(MAX(time), MIN(time), SECOND) diff
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
),
checkpoints AS (
  SELECT TIME_ADD(min_time, INTERVAL step SECOND) start_time, TIME_ADD(min_time, INTERVAL step + 2 SECOND) end_time
  FROM period, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, diff + 2, 2)) step
)
SELECT start_time time, SUM(viewCount) viewCount
FROM checkpoints c
JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
ON t.time >= c.start_time AND t.time < c.end_time
GROUP BY start_time
ORDER BY start_time, time
```

and result is:

```sql
Row time        viewCount    
1   00:00:00    75   
2   00:00:02    149  
3   00:00:04    145  
4   00:00:06    134
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 4):

Supposing that you actually have a TIMESTAMP column, you can use an approach like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(
    UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp) -
    MOD(UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp), 15 * 60)
  ) AS time,
  SUM(viewCount) AS viewCount
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY time;
```

It relies on conversion to and from Unix seconds in order to compute the 15 minute intervals. Note that it will not produce a row with a zero count for an empty 15 minute interval unlike Mikhail's solution, however (it's not clear if this is important to you).

Comment: from my experience  - filling gaps is important in this type of analysis

Comment: Thanks for the solution